# MechanicalSoup follow a link without inside a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, mechanicalsoup

I am writing an application which scraps some data from the internet using [MechanicalSoup](https://github.com/MechanicalSoup/MechanicalSoup). I've already covered `login` process etc. The page that I end with contains an `html` table. The problem is, the data is incomplete. There's a `Show more` button, which allows the user to display the full data. Here's how it looks like (under `Inspect`):

```
<a class="text-white btn btn-success" href="#" id="expand" style="margin-bottom:30px;">Show more</a>
```

I know that it calls `jQuery` function. The problem is that of course `MechanicalSoup` is unable to click it, it can only follow its link.

Using this code I can find this link:

```
l = browser.find_link(id='expand')
print(type(l), l)
print(browser.follow_link(l))

print(browser.get_url())
```

I can identify that it's `bs4.Element.Tag` but when I want to follow it (the response is `200`, so I guess its good) - it doesn't follow it. Basically this would add `#` to the page URL and after reading page text I would notice a difference (or I even tried `launch_browser()` - it displays the incomplete table as well):

```
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'> <a class="text-white btn btn-success" href="#" id="expand" style="margin-bottom:30px;">Show more</a>
<Response [200]>
<page_url_without_#_at_the_end>
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? Or is it impossible to follow that kind of link with this library?

Comment: It sounds like by clicking the "Show more" button, a javascript function is executed to populate the rest of the page. In this case, the `href="#"` is not meaningful. You could test this assumption by adding "#" to the URL in your web browser -- I suspect the page would not change. If so, then you will need to use a tool other than MechanicalSoup (see https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#form-submission-has-no-effect-or-fails).

Comment: Yes, I actually figured it myself, forgot to check here. Had to switch to `Selenium`