# Using Mechanicalsoup to navigate multiple pages / forms

Tags: python, json, api, web-scraping, mechanicalsoup

I've had success using mechanicalsoup with single pages / single forms, but am having difficulty with a multistep problem. The pages I am attempting to navigate start here: https://webapps2.ncua.gov/CustomQuery/CUSelect.aspx

I get through the first page/form, but then I am not sure how to deal with the second page/form. The third page includes the result that I wish to scrape.

```
import requests
import urllib.parse
import mechanicalsoup

browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open("https://webapps2.ncua.gov/CustomQuery/CUSelect.aspx")
form=browser.select_form()
browser["operand0"] = "State"
browser["operator0"] = "Not Equal"
browser["value0"] = "XX"

response = browser.submit_selected()

form2 = browser.get_current_form()

submit = browser.get_current_page().find('input', id='BtnAllAcct')
form2.choose_submit(submit)
browser.submit_selected()
submit = browser.get_current_page().find('input', id='Btndata1')
form2.choose_submit(submit)
browser.submit_selected()
```

Any ideas? This is my second attempt after first trying to interact with the API, but two separate forms is stumping me on that as well.

Comment: What's the problem with the code you're posting? What do you get? What did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I was solving a similar issue, following the advice in [MechanicalSoup follow a link without inside a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53799550/mechanicalsoup-follow-a-link-without-inside-a-button) I switched to selenium

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33113489)